# Why does Point allow you to access x and y directly?

Tags: java, awt

Both `x` and `y` and integers, while `getX()` and `getY()` returns a doubles.

Why aren't there e.g. `getXIntValue()`, `getXDoubleValue()` and vice versa for `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, it's because it's ancient. But I like it because it saves typing and adds clarity; IMHO getters and setters can be a waste of time for simple classes if they're public and all they're going to do is to return the value and set it, which is all you want 99% of the time.

Design philosophy changed and now everything uses them. But things are coming full circle and in a modern languages like Groovy these would be "properties" with getters / setters inferred and syntax pretty similar to that for accessing public fields in Java.

E.g. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans

**Edit**: and according to an (unofficial) [Scala style guide](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/18295),

> Note that fields may actually be used in a number of situations where accessors and
>   mutators would be required in languages like Java. Always prefer fields over methods
>   when given the choice.

Comment: Thanks. Reading this just wants to make me switch over to Groovy. :)

Answer (score 5):

Note the @since in the Javadoc -- 1.0

There is broad consensus that Point was very poorly designed.

Comment: `@since 1.0` in the JRE is analogous to "crap design".

Answer (score 4):

Point extends Point2D and Point2D has getX() and getY() defined as returning double. As @Dilum mentions above, its bad design from the stone ages of java.